# Can we make the Codable key in struct as case insensitive in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, codable, decodable

Can we make the Codable key case insensitive?
NOT VALUE but the KEY ITSELF needs to be case insensitive

```
struct Model: Codable, Equatable {
let number: String?
let id: String?
let address: String?

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
case number = "A-Number"
case id = "A-Id"
case address = "AddressId"
}
}
```

So that it works for both json:

```
Sample Json 1
{
"A-Number" : "12345",
"A-Id" : "1",
"AddressId" : "3456"
}

Sample Json 2
{
"a-number" : "12345",
"a-id" : "1",
"addressid" : "3456"
}
```

Comment: `JSONDecoder.KeyDecodingStrategy.custom(_:)` ?

Comment: Is that the whole JSON? Is there other struct that should handle case insensitive cases? You could use for instance https://pastebin.com/KMrNJYRr or https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder/keydecodingstrategy/custom (see the example), depending on yoour final needs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use the below code for making the keys lowercase, so that you can use throught your application.
NOTE: All your keys will be lowercased with this solution, if you want to use them.

```
struct AnyKey: CodingKey {
      var stringValue: String

      init?(stringValue: String) {
        self.stringValue = stringValue
      }

      var intValue: Int? {
        return nil
      }

      init?(intValue: Int) {
        return nil
      }
    }
    
    struct DecodingStrategy {
        static var lowercase: ([CodingKey]) -> CodingKey {
            return { keys -> CodingKey in
                let key = keys.first!
                let modifiedKey = key.stringValue.prefix(1).lowercased() + key.stringValue.dropFirst()
                return AnyKey(stringValue: modifiedKey)!
            }
        }
    }
```

To use this:

```
let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
jsonDecoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .custom(DecodingStrategy.lowercase)
let dataModel = try jsonDecoder.decode(YourDataModel, from: yourdata)
```